# Unknown folder generated in Derived data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, deriveddata

I have a project which was working fine till I was working on my older MacBook. I am now working on new MacBook and the same project gives me build error. My friend also works on the new MacBook with same configuration and os but he is able to build it successfully.
Error on my system is :

```
<unknown>:0: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-dlhksnilacudcebpmorlzpzlkbid/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyProject.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyProject.build/DerivedSources/CoreDataGenerated/Model/Model+CoreDataModel.swift'

Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code
```

I have navigated to the path

'/Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-dlhksnilacudcebpmorlzpzlkbid/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyProject.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyProject.build/DerivedSources/CoreDataGenerated/Model'

There I found an unknown folder named "emplate" under which the required file exists.

I have searched the whole project, build settings, build phases, scripts but nowhere I found "emplate".

The CoreData entity Codegen has been specified as "Category/Extension".

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Its better if you can install new version xcode or use same version of xcode which your friend is using, i think some path issues with your current xcode

Comment: We are using same version of Xcode. New version Xcode can't be used due to some project library limitations.

Comment: you can try by deleting old xcode and install new xcode and keep it in application folder

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution for this. Renamed and Moved Xcode from Desktop to Applications folder, clean the project , removed DerivedData folder. And it works.